# Spotify API: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, asynchronous

I am getting the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` when I try to run my code. I have looked up the error code and all the answers are about a circular reference. However, I do not understand where my code contains a circular reference

I have a function as part of my React app which saves a playlist. The function takes two arguments -playlistName (a string) and trackURIs (an array of strings). Here is the function in question

```
async savePlaylist(playlistName, trackURIs) {
    //checks if playlistName and trackURIs are already set (i.e. we already 'ran' the function)
    if (!(playlistName && trackURIs)) return;
    
    //setup for GET request that gets userID
    let currentAccessToken = accessToken;
    let headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentAccessToken}` };
    let userID = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
      headers: headers,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => jsonResponse.id)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`User is Fetch error: ${error}`);
      });

    //POST request to create playlist
    let playlistID = await fetch(
      `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userID}/playlists`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentAccessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: playlistName
        }),
        json: true,
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => jsonResponse.id)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Playlist creation error: ${error}`);
      });

    await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentAccessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        uris: trackURIs,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) =>
        console.log(`Songs added to the playlist: ${response}`)
      )
      .catch((error) =>
        console.log(`Error adding songs to playlist: ${error}`)
      );
  }
```

The part of the function that seems to be giving me issues (based on console error) is this:

```
let playlistID = await fetch(
      `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userID}/playlists`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentAccessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: playlistName
        }),
        json: true,
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => jsonResponse.id)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Playlist creation error: ${error}`);
      });
```

The exact line that my error points me to is this

```
 body: JSON.stringify({
          name: playlistName
        })
```

So it seems like something about referencing the argument playlistName in the JSON.stringify method is causing an issue - but I don't quite know **why** its an issue. I have done some reading on circular references, but I don't see how it applies in my case.

Here is where the function is called in my App.js file:

```
savePlaylist() {
    console.log('Saving playlist')
    let trackURIs = this.state.playlistTracks.map((track) => track.URI)
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackURIs)
    //this.setState({playlistName: "",  playlistTracks: []})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of digging into the code, I found the circular reference (annoying but a good learning experience).

Here is the issue - hopefully it helps someone else catch a similar issue one day :)

**Setup**

I was defining the savePlaylist method in my App.js file as such, with the call to the Spotify objects savePlaylist function, passing it playlistName from my state, as well as track URIs. Check my original post if you want full details on the method on the Spotify object.

```
  savePlaylist() {
    console.log('Saving playlist')
    let trackURIs = this.state.playlistTracks.map((track) => track.URI)
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackURIs)
    this.setState({playlistName: "",  playlistTracks: []})
  }
```

Another relevant function to this issue here is this one (defined in App.js file)

```
 updatePlaylistName (name) {
    this.setState({playlistName: name})
  }
```

I was passing these methods (among others) to my Playlist component as such

```
<Playlist
playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
onRemove={this.removeTrack}
onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
onSave={this.savePlaylist}
/>
```

**The Issue**

Here is the full code for that playlist component, as I had before I made the fix

```
export class Playlist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleNameChange(e) {
    this.props.onNameChange(e)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Playlist">
        <input defaultValue={"New Playlist"} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
        <TrackList
          tracks={this.props.playlistTracks}
          onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
          isRemoval={true}
        />
        <button className="Playlist-save" onClick={this.props.onSave}>SAVE TO SPOTIFY</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The issue line, in particular, was this

```
 handleNameChange(e) {
    this.props.onNameChange(e)
  }
```

In my handleNameChange method, I was passing the entire event object to onNameChange (a props function that corresponds to the updatePlaylistName function defined in App.js). In reality, I want to pass the event target value to this function, as such.

```
handleNameChange(e) {
    this.props.onNameChange(e.target.value)
  }
```

I made this change, and everything works as expected.